# Phrase meaning "constantly judged" or "criticized"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm looking for a word or phrase which means constantly being judged or viewed mockingly or with a sense of stereotype/criticism.

For example,

> The company I founded was viewed with a sense of ______

I am the founder of the company. We are being judged because of our values. People think we should be more cunning while our culture is against
Wall Street cut-throating. I'm writing an essay on that. Thus we are being judged, mocked and criticized.

Comment: "My company was the butt of all jokes", "My company was ridiculed on every corner"...  But not enough context, most likely.  Besides, it sounds whiny.

Comment: What @Victor said. So for the *specific* context posed by OP, *My company was viewed with a sense of **ridicule***. Or *My company was treated with a degree of **levity***, for example.

Comment: It would be helpful to if you could finish your example sentence around the blank spot where the phrase or word should go. I think you want a sense that it's unfair criticism, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This does seem like some sort of business discussion so you really would want to be careful to not sound whiny. // "Disparage" is another word that I've heard used in business settings. The connotation is that the disparaging remarks were unfair or improper.

Comment: Add some more context. You founded the company? Who's being judged here?

Comment: Yeah I am the founder. We are being judged because of our values. People think we should be more cunning while our culture is against wall street cut throating. I'm writing an essay on that. Thus we are being judged, mocked and criticized.

Comment: The more you expose yourselves, the more attention you attract, the more there might be ridicule, judgement, mockery, and so forth. Be prepared for that before you publish your essay.  Some people have nothing better to do...  Also, consider not using such made up terms like "cut throating".

Comment: Thanks for adding the context - it really helps. I'll give it some thought. I have [quixotic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quixotic) tendencies myself, so being teased for being too idealistic is something I'm familiar with ;)

Comment: You may want to shift your thought into active voice. "while some people criticized the company I founded because they viewed our principles as too idealistic..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a hard time finding a phrase with the exact nuance you've described. Some that come close:

[Disparage](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/disparage?q=disparage) - to suggest that somebody/something is not important or valuable

> The company I founded was disparaged by those who believed that we were too idealistic.

[Ridicule](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ridicule_2) - to make somebody/something look silly by laughing at them or it in an unkind way.

> The company I founded was ridiculed by those who believed that we were too idealistic.

[Jeer](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/jeer_1#jeer_1__4) - to laugh at somebody or shout rude remarks at them to show that you do not respect them.

> The company I founded was jeered at by those who believed that we were too idealistic.

Disparaged is the most formal of these choices. Jeer has a sense of loud, provocative statements and is similar to taunting. Ridicule has a sense of derision, or not worth taking seriously.

Actually,  I  think [derision](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/derision?q=derision) would fit into your original example well.

> The company I founded was viewed with derision because of our values.

I wouldn't use "was derided" in my dialect. It's much less common than derision, even though it is grammatical. I might also phrase it

> "The company I founded was an object of derision because ..."

Answer (score -1):

You may want "nitpicked", although without more context it's hard to be sure. As in:

> The company I founded was nitpicked [by|for|because of]...

But I agree that when you're talking about yourself or your own company it does come across as whiny.

Comment: Nitpicked doesn't have the sense of mockery that the question is asking for nor the sense of being pigeon-holed by an unflattering stereotype. It's just criticism over tiny things that aren't that important.

Comment: Speaking of which... ;-)